# Tkinter maximize/restore/resize differentiation

Tags: python, event-handling, tkinter, resize

I know in Tkinter that the `"<Configure>"` event handles size changes in a window. However, I need to distinguish between when a user hits the maximize button, the restore button and when the user is resizing the window (instead of all three at once). Any ideas on how to do this? Is there a standard way? For instance, when a user hits maximize, I want to execute my code to maximize. When the user hits restore, I want to execute different code to restore. When the user drags to resize (or uses the keyboard shortcut to do so) I want it to execute different code altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of a built-in way to track these events, but you could use the [`state()`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm#M62) method on your root window to track changes. You can check the returned values of `state()`, specifically `normal` and `zoomed` (looks like Windows and OSX only), and call your own methods to handle the resize type based off those values. Here's a example to clarify:

```
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        # initialize the new_state
        self.new_state = 'normal'

        self.parent.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_handler)

    def _resize_handler(self, event):
        self.old_state = self.new_state # assign the old state value
        self.new_state = self.parent.state() # get the new state value

        if self.new_state == 'zoomed':
            print('maximize event')
        elif self.new_state == 'normal' and self.old_state == 'zoomed':
            print('restore event')
        else:
            print('dragged resize event')


root = Tk()
App(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

If you want to distinguish between dragging the window and dragging to resize, you'll have to add some extra checks, maybe storing the size before `<Configure>` and the size after, with `winfo_height()` and `winfo_width()`, and if no change occurs, you know the window was only repositioned.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Interesting. The only states I see on my Linux system are iconic and normal. I wonder why they don't include zoomed. Anyway, I'll accept your answer, but if someone else happens to find a more cross-platform way (it need not be built-in per se), I may or may not switch. It's great to know it can be done on Windows and Mac, at least.